# Odds Ratio - how many times more likely?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, probability

Problem: I need to figure out how many times are women more likely to continue attending a class after a certain period of time.

Data:

[image]

Solution: I used odds ratio (see picture).

Is it correct to assume that women are 2.8 times more likely to continue with the class compare to men?
[image]

Cohort 1: 0.59 / 0.34 = 1.7

Cohort 2: 0.40 / 0.65 = 0.61

Odds Ratio = 1.7 / 0.61 = 2.8

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't aware this website existed!